# PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/content/drive/MyDrive/TransVOD_Lite/swinb1/swinb_checkpoint0048.pth'

Tags: object, permissions, detection

I am trying to implement the https://github.com/qianyuzqy/TransVOD_Lite/tree/main on **Google colab** and when I try to run

> ! dd
> sudo GPUS_PER_NODE=1 tools/run_dist_launch.sh $1 /content/drive/MyDrive/TransVOD_Lite/TransVOD_Lite/swinb/2swinb_checkpoint0048.pth $2 configs/swinb_train_single.sh

i got the following error

> !
> PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: .../swinb/2swinb_checkpoint0048.pth'

could you please direct me how can I solve the persmission error?

Try to run an object detection model but got permission [Error 13].